# Calculate Time to the Previous 10 Minute Boundary in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a process that sends an email every 10 minutes on the 10 minute boundary.
i.e. sends at 10:10, 10:20, 10:30, 10:40 etc.

After a short delay, I have a Gmail API call that reads the inbox the above emails were sent to and confirm their arrival. However, I only want to check back to the previous 10 minute boundary.

In other words:

Email sent at 10:50, the api call will check back from 10:50 onwards.
Email sent at 16:20, the api call will check back from 16:20 onwards.

I need this to be in Javascript so I can use the "q" parameter in the Gmail api call and set up the "in:sent after" time which I think has to be in epoch seconds so it can be used in any timezone.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: So you want the last 10 minute boundary from the current time?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 1):

You can use some modulo maths to set the current time *minutes* to the last 10 minute boundary

```js
// Some example dates
const dates = [
  new Date(),                    // now
  new Date(2022, 11, 8, 10, 52), // 10:52
  new Date(2022, 11, 8, 16, 29), // 16:29
  new Date(2022, 11, 8, 12, 00), // midday
];

dates.forEach((sentAfter) => {
  const min = sentAfter.getMinutes(); // get current minute
  sentAfter.setSeconds(0, 0);
  sentAfter.setMinutes(min - (min % 10)); // subtract the modulo of 10

  console.log("Time:", sentAfter.toLocaleTimeString());
  console.log("Timestamp (seconds):", sentAfter.getTime() / 1000);
});
```

Comment: That's great, but can I get that that time converted into epoch seconds.

Comment: @jatsad yep, just use `getTime() / 1000`. I'll update the answer

Comment: Shouldn't really be a need for `Math.floor()` since I've zero'd out the seconds and milliseconds but can't hurt to be extra safe